# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object during migrating to oracle db

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I added a new model in models.py. And I am successfully done with makemigrations. During makemigrations, I haven't faced any issue. But when I tried to migrate this model to the DB server, I am getting error as `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.` I am sure that there is no other model name with this new model name.
Could you please let me know what is the issue and the resolution. Thanks in advance

models.py

```
class ProdServersMountPoints(models.Model):

    mountpoint          =   models.CharField(max_length=100)
    check_fabs_servers  =   models.BooleanField()
    check_oc_servers    =   models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PROD_SERVERS_MOUNTPOINTS'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mountpoint)
```

Error:

```
(venv_2.7.12) -bash-4.1$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, fabi, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying fabi.0002_auto_20171205_0057...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 295, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 112, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 481, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing     object
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not print out the failing sql and determine what is the cause, edit the following:

"/scratch/kvkumari/tools_setup/Python/framework/venv_2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py",
 Just before line 481 where the execute function is called add:

```
print query
```

This will show you the failing sql query. You can then remove or rename the failing sql table or object

Comment: That was very useful, thank you, I added that and was able to get with our DBA to fix it.